# Global OSX KeyRepeat settings failing to being implemented

Tags: macos

I am trying to implement blazing fast keyboard repeating in OSX 10.8.4

[Here](https://github.com/olorton/dotfiles/blob/master/osx/osx-settings#L36) is the relevant dotfile I am running.

Which looks like this:

```
echo "Disable press-and-hold for keys in favor of key repeat"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false

echo "Set a blazingly fast keyboard repeat rate"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0.02

echo "Set a shorter Delay until key repeat"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 15
```

The effect is that after logging out and in (or rebooting) sometimes Terminal.app and Sublime Text pick up the changes, but it doesn't last for long. I have tested this on both my home and work Macs and I cannot make the settings apply successfully.

I have looked at `.GlobalPreferences.plist` and the settings are there.

```
open ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about development this would be on topic on AskDifferent

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of AskDifferent. It turns out that KeyRemap4MacBook overrides the settings that I had [as discovered here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x/83923#83923).